# How to change plugin tags on wordpress.org?

Tags: wordpress

How to change tags of the plugin? The first time it was loaded into the wordpress.org repository, some tags were specified, but with subsequent updates it was decided to change them, and this was done in Readme file. But now when searching for keywords, for some reason old tags work and new one not. And on the wordpress.org plugin page the old ones are output.

As an example, images of the public Jetpack plugin have same thing as i see:

---

### [Plugin page on wordpress.org](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H3WNy.png)

### [different tags in last update from readme file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZVnCx.png)

Thanks

Comment: What is the link to your plugin?

Comment: why you minus post? no link because NDA...

Comment: I haven't down voted. Also, if it's in the WordPress.org directory, it's open for every to see and use, so an NDA would be violated if it's in the WordPress.org directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a [look at this page](https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/wordpress-org/how-your-readme-txt-works/#example-readme) which explains how plugin `readme.txt` files work. In outlines that the read me file accepts multiple file headers, one of them being `tags`. Only the first five tags are shown and used for search though.

An example:

```
=== Plugin Name ===
Contributors: (this should be a list of wordpress.org userid's)
Donate link: http://example.com/
Tags: comments, spam
Requires at least: 3.0.1
Tested up to: 3.4
Requires PHP: 5.2.4
Stable tag: 4.3
License: GPLv2 or later
License URI: http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-2.0.html
```

In the example above, `comments` and `spam` will be used as tags within the directory. You can have tags with multiple words too by just including spaces normally. The tags are split with commas.

If you're not seeing an update, make sure the `readme.txt` file in the SVN `trunk` folder **and** the latest stable version in the `tags` folder are using the same tags. Ensuring consistency between `trunk` and the latest `tags` version will just make things easier, however the plugin directory parser stops reading once it sees the latest stable tag and will then read that file instead.

Comment: yes, that's what i want to know
"Only the first five tags are shown and used for search though."
Thank you!